# Follow a .pcap file in wireshark like tail -f

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have a .pcap file on my android device, that I can access from my PC with wireshark via smb and wondering if it possible to get a 'Live view' of that file in wireshark.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
tail -f -c +0 foo.pcap | wireshark -k -i -
```

With:

- `tail -f -c +0`: Feed the capture file to wireshark
- `-k`: Start the capture session immediately
- `-i -`: Capture from STDIN

Reference: [Wireshark feeding from stdin](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes#Stdin)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [`pcaptail`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921152123/http://blog.tobez.org:80/posts/pcaptail/) which does exactly that ([direct download](http://www.tobez.org/download/pcaptail-0.01.tar.gz)).

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @CarsonIp Thanks! Unfortunately his blog seems to be down, the download is still valid though. I added an archive.org-link to the blog post as well as a direct download link to the code.

Comment: I tried that already. I even had to change some source code to get it compiled. Later I realize there's a way easier method to pipe input into wireshark.